Determine asymptotically how many positive integers ≤ x are odd, squarefree, and have an even number of prime divisor
I have known the proportion of the number of odd squarefree intergers to numbers less than x, and I also know the proportion of the number of squarefree integers that have even number of prime divisors. But I have no idea whether these two conditions can be considered independent? Please give me some hints QAQ
Thank you very much

https://oeis.org/A056912 versus https://oeis.org/A056913 claim the ones with an odd number of prime factors and the ones with an even number of prime factors have the same asymptotic density. How the density evolves for large $x$, I do not know.

Please elaborate on the significance of the phrase "determine asymptotically".

As a start : The "proportion" of the squarefree numbers is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

@Peter We are looking at odd squarefree numbers here.

@Arthur This is only the first step.
